# MSP430 MPU9250 MPU6050 I2C: After sending the address NACK

Tags: sensor, i2c, msp430

I have a problem with read from my MPU6050/MPU9250. Both are connected with AD0 to ground so both should have the address `0x68`. With both sensors the same behaviour occurs. I'm testing them *individually*. I recently bought the mpu9250 where i wasn't able to read data. In a another project i was able to read data from mpu6050 using a stm32.

If i used this code on MSP430FR5969 launchpad evaluation kit with P1.6 as SDA and P1.7 as SCK, after setting the start condition for I2C-communication using `UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTR + UCTXSTT;` the ´TXIEFG0´ flag and the ´NACKIE´ flag are set.

Afterwards `0x75` is written to the write buffer in ISR but never sent out.

I searched the internet for 4 hours but nobody seems to have ever discovered this problem. What are possible reasons?

After initialization my registers look like this:
[image: registers]

[image: registers2]

```
#include "driverlib.h"
#include "MPU9250_reg.h"

/* Slave address */
// b110100X with X = 0 (ADO is connected to ground)=> 0x68
#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x68
#define SLAVE_ADDRESS_READ  0x11010001
#define SLAVE_ADDRESS_WRITE ((SLAVE_ADDRESS << 1)|0x00)

volatile uint8_t a;
volatile uint8_t byte_counter;
int main(void) {

    WDT_A_hold(WDT_A_BASE);

    // Configure Pins for I2C
       //Set P1.6 and P1.7 as Secondary Module Function Input.
       /*

       * Select Port 1
       * Set Pin 6, 7 to input Secondary Module Function, (UCB0SIMO/UCB0SDA, UCB0SOMI/UCB0SCL).
       */
       GPIO_setAsPeripheralModuleFunctionInputPin(
           GPIO_PORT_P1,
           GPIO_PIN6 + GPIO_PIN7,
           GPIO_SECONDARY_MODULE_FUNCTION
       );

           EUSCI_B_I2C_initMasterParam param = {0};
           param.selectClockSource = EUSCI_B_I2C_CLOCKSOURCE_SMCLK;
           param.i2cClk = CS_getSMCLK();
           param.dataRate = EUSCI_B_I2C_SET_DATA_RATE_100KBPS;
           param.byteCounterThreshold = 0;
           param.autoSTOPGeneration = EUSCI_B_I2C_NO_AUTO_STOP;
           EUSCI_B_I2C_initMaster(EUSCI_B0_BASE, &param);

           PMM_unlockLPM5();
           __bis_SR_register(GIE);


           //Specify slave address
           EUSCI_B_I2C_setSlaveAddress(EUSCI_B0_BASE,
                       SLAVE_ADDRESS_WRITE
                       );

           //Set Master in transmit mode
           EUSCI_B_I2C_setMode(EUSCI_B0_BASE,
                       EUSCI_B_I2C_TRANSMIT_MODE
                       );

           //Enable I2C Module to start operations
           EUSCI_B_I2C_enable(EUSCI_B0_BASE);

           // ensure it not busy
           while(UCB0STATW & UCBBUSY){}

           // send a Stop condition
           UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP;
           while(!(UCB0CTLW0 & UCTXSTP)){}

           EUSCI_B_I2C_enableInterrupt(EUSCI_B0_BASE, EUSCI_B_I2C_TRANSMIT_INTERRUPT0);
           byte_counter = 1;
           UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTR + UCTXSTT;
           // after this step the UCTXIEF0 and the UCNACKIFG flag are set

    while(1)
    {
        _nop();
    }
}


#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector=USCI_B0_VECTOR
__interrupt
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
__attribute__((interrupt(USCI_B0_VECTOR)))
#endif
void USCIB0_ISR(void)
{
    switch(__even_in_range(UCB0IV, USCI_I2C_UCBIT9IFG))
    {
        case USCI_NONE:             // No interrupts break;
            break;
        case USCI_I2C_UCALIFG:      // Arbitration lost
            break;
        case USCI_I2C_UCNACKIFG:    // NAK received (master only)
            break;
        case USCI_I2C_UCSTTIFG:     // START condition detected with own address (slave mode only)
            break;
        case USCI_I2C_UCSTPIFG:     // STOP condition detected (master & slave mode)
            break;
        case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG3:     // RXIFG3
            break;
        case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG3:     // TXIFG3
            break;
        case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG2:     // RXIFG2
            break;
        case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG2:     // TXIFG2
            break;
        case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG1:     // RXIFG1
            break;
        case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG1:     // TXIFG1
            break;
        case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG0:     // RXIFG0
            // will never be reached cause there a NACK after sending the slave address
            // would be used for receiving
            while(1){}
            break;
        case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG0:     // TXIFG0
            if(byte_counter == 1)
            {
                // won't be send cause there the NACK before?
                UCB0TXBUF = 0x75;
                byte_counter--;
            }
            else if(byte_counter == 0)
            {
                // clear and disable interrupt
                EUSCI_B_I2C_clearInterrupt(EUSCI_B0_BASE, EUSCI_B_I2C_TRANSMIT_INTERRUPT0);
                EUSCI_B_I2C_disableInterrupt(EUSCI_B0_BASE, EUSCI_B_I2C_TRANSMIT_INTERRUPT0);

                // change to receive mode
                UCB0CTLW0 &= ~(UCTR);

                // enable receive interrupt
                EUSCI_B_I2C_enableInterrupt(EUSCI_B0_BASE, EUSCI_B_I2C_RECEIVE_INTERRUPT0);


                // send start signal with READ
                //Specify slave address
                EUSCI_B_I2C_setSlaveAddress(EUSCI_B0_BASE,
                            SLAVE_ADDRESS_READ
                            );
                UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTT;
            }
            else
            {
                // not aloud
                while(1){}
            }
            break;
        case USCI_I2C_UCBCNTIFG:    // Byte count limit reached (UCBxTBCNT)
            break;
        case USCI_I2C_UCCLTOIFG:    // Clock low timeout - clock held low too long
            break;
        case USCI_I2C_UCBIT9IFG:    // Generated on 9th bit of a transmit (for debugging)
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I2C devices should have different addresses. Connect one device' A0 to Vcc via a pull up resistor, so it will have address 0x69.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I corrected my question. I'm testing only one at a time. I just used both to see if one is broken. I was able to read from MPU6050 using a stm32 but i'm not with the msp430.

Comment: How are you testing them individually? are you disconnecting the one you are not using from the bus?

Answer (score 1):

The slave address is 0x68 (1101000), but the code uses address 0xD0 (11010000), which is not even possible because normal I²C slave addresses have only 7 bits.

And there is no reason to set the slave address again before the repeated start.

(It appears you have confused the I²C address with the first I²C byte, which combines the seven bits of the address with the read/write bit.)